# Vim mode in FreeBSD shell?

Tags: freebsd, tcsh, csh, vi-mode

How can I switch to Vim mode in FreeBSD shell?

I echoed the value of `$SHELL` and it is `/bin/csh` however `man csh` opens `tsch`'s manual page.

`set -o` and `shopts` are not available as well.

And `/etc/inputrc` (Readline) is not there too.

Should I install `bash` or is it possible to have `Vim` line editing mode rather than Emacs natively, without having to install other shells?

Thanks in advance.

---

I am on FreeBSD 11.

Comment: According to the `tcsh` manual, you should be able to use `bindkey -v` to switch to Vi keybindings. If you get the `tcsh` manual when you do `man csh` it probably means that `csh` is in fact `tcsh` or at least that `tcsh` is installed on the system already.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've actually came accross that command. I think its a feature of `tcsh` exclusively, and `csh` don't have `vi` mode at all. First, when I issued that command I expected the cursor to "drop" to the previous character as in the case with `bash` and `fish`, and `zsh` if I'm not wrong; it didn't, so I inferred it didn't switched the mode (after pressing `Esc` or `^[` that is). It's actually more appropriate to not to drop (the cursor) to the previous character when switching the mode, and it's faster.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csh` shell does not have Vi keybindings, while `tcsh` has.

The `tcsh` shell is available in the FreeBSD base system (as is `sh`, which on FreeBSD is `ash`, the Almquist shell).

To switch to Vi keybindings with the `tcsh` shell, use

```
bindkey -v
```